# Spring security permission

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

Current Requirement is to secure data using Spring security. Imagine a situation where admin can select any user and grants rights so that he will have permission to edit details of specific customer details in the form.
Ex: Suppose there are 6 user. Now admin can grants rights to these 6 user as lets say user 1,2 can edit customer A,B,C form. and user3,4 can edit custom D,E,F form.There can be N number of user and M number of customer. The form will be shown in disabled mode to the user who  does not have right to edit the customer form.Those who have rights they can edit the form.
How can I acheive this  using spring security. Spring security has something like hasRole ..but that is very specific.I want something like hasPermission.Tell  me how can I check hasPermission in jsp and then as per permission I can show form as disabled or enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This requirement -- granting permissions on particular instances of secured objects -- is better satisfied with access-control lists than with roles.  See Spring's reference documentation on "[Domain Object Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/domain-acls.html)".